# PostgreSQL crash when connection failed

Tags: windows, postgresql

Error log is :

```
016-02-21 21:22:34 GET DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 83: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"
....
....
2016-02-21 21:22:37 GET DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 83: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"
2016-02-21 21:22:37 GET FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2016-02-21 21:22:37 GET DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 83: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"
2016-02-21 21:22:37 GET LOG:  CreateProcess call failed: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.

     (error code 299)
2016-02-21 21:22:37 GET LOG:  could not fork new process for connection: No error
2016-02-21 21:22:37 GET LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2016-02-21 21:22:38 GET FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2016-02-21 21:22:38 GET DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 83: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"
2016-02-21 21:22:42 GET FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2016-02-21 21:22:42 GET DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 83: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"
2016-02-21 21:24:26 GET LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
2016-02-21 21:24:26 GET LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2016-02-21 21:24:29 GET FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2016-02-21 21:24:45 GET PANIC:  could not write to log file 000000010000000100000041 at offset 4259840, length 8192: Invalid argument
2016-02-21 21:24:45 GET STATEMENT:  COMMIT
2016-02-21 21:24:53 GET LOG:  server process (PID 470944) was terminated by exception 0xC0000409
2016-02-21 21:24:53 GET DETAIL:  Failed process was running: COMMIT
2016-02-21 21:24:53 GET HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
2016-02-21 21:24:53 GET LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

Can anyone help to solve the problem ,I spent many hours but dont find solution. **PG VERSION is 9.4** 
 Operating System: Windows

**PostgreSQL.conf:** is :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432 
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 128MB  
dynamic_shared_memory_type = windows
```

**pg_hba.conf** is :

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name CentOS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sory my mistake, OS is windows